# Cruise control with C++

Tags: c++, cruisecontrol

Is it possible to use the CruiseControl tool with a C++ (Mingw) project on Windows? I need to be able  to download the latest sources from XVN, build them, send reports by mail. The application is using http server (lightpd) for work.

So main question is have to use it for email notifications?
Problem is I dont see any destination field in email tag.

I am interested in sending email notifications after build which executes in batch file. 
E. g. in my config file I call batch file which executes build, after that I need to send email notification, how can I do it ?

Comment: if there are anu similiar tools with same functionality for C++ projects?

Comment: You put a 50-point bounty on a yes-no question. Don't you think it would have been better to ask *how* to use Cruise Control, instead of just asking whether it's possible?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Just answer "yes" and get +50! Wooohooo! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is possible. There is a [Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en) for Windows, a command line [SVN clients](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows), you can invoke [`gmake`](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/) or any other build system you are using along with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), there is even a [support for a Visual Studio projects](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/UsingCruiseControlWithCplusPlus) if you need it. There are a lot of people using [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) for C++ projects, thus a lot of documentation, tutorials and examples available online.

Comment: please share with me this stuff, specially for sending email notifications

Comment: @unresolved_external: It sounds like it is a good time for you to read CC documentation, or perhaps use Google. This stuff is no secret, you use CC tasks, write XML and achieve your goals. Here is one of examples of sending email, for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835572/how-do-i-send-an-email-in-cruisecontrol-net-that-contains-the-svn-commit-message

Comment: it is for cc.net, what i need to use is standard cc

Comment: @unresolved_external: Then refer to http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html. There are tons of tasks, you can use `email`/`htmlemail`, some example is also here - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ap11146/. RTFM :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly what you're asking for, but is there anything preventing you from using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)? People I've talked to that maintains the continuous integration for a living that have used both Jenkins as well as cruise control prefers Jenkins. Of course the bonus with Jenkins is that it's free.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a script that checks out and builds your project from the command line (in Cygwin's bash, for example), then you can certainly integrate the build into cruise control or Jenkins.

I don't know much about cruise control, but we use Jenkins a lot, and even though it has bugs that need to be worked around overall we find it extremely useful for CI and nightly build jobs.

Regarding the email aspect, Jenkins can be configured to watch the SVN log and when a build fails it can send an email to the people that committed changes since the last successful build. This functionality can be enabled with minimal configuration. There are add-ons that allow you to configure the content of the emails as well.